# Rating system with stars

Tags: javascript, html, css, rate

I am looking long time for a star rating system. I need something that is quite simple and that works! Here is what i've tried:

```js
    $(':radio').change(
      function(){
        $('.choice').text( this.value + ' stars' );
      } 
    )
```

```css
    //reset, center n shiz (don't mind this stuff)
    *, ::after, ::before{
      height: 100%;
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      text-align: center;  
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    body{
      font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", 
      Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
      &::before{
        height: 100%;
        content:'';
        width:0;
        background:red;
        vertical-align: middle;
        display:inline-block;
      }
    }

.star-rating{
      font-size:0;
      white-space:nowrap;
      display:inline-block;
      width:250px;
      height:50px;
      overflow:hidden;
      position:relative;
      background:
          url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjREREREREIiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
      background-size: contain;
      i{
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 20%;
        z-index: 1;
        background: 
            url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjRkZERjg4IiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');  
        background-size: contain;
      }
      input{ 
        -moz-appearance:none;
        -webkit-appearance:none;
        opacity: 0;
        display:inline-block;
        width: 20%;
        height: 100%; 
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        z-index: 2;
        position: relative;
        &:hover + i,
        &:checked + i{
          opacity:1;    
        }
      }
      i ~ i{
        width: 40%;
      }
      i ~ i ~ i{
        width: 60%;
      }
      i ~ i ~ i ~ i{
        width: 80%;
      }
      i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i{
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
    
    //JUST COSMETIC STUFF FROM HERE ON. THESE AREN'T THE DROIDS YOU ARE LOOKING FOR: MOVE ALONG. 
    
    //just styling for the number
    .choice{
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 20px;
      display:block;
    }
```

```html
    <span class="star-rating">
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"><i></i>
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><i></i>
    </span>
    <strong class="choice">Choose a rating</strong>
```

That is from [THIS SITE](http://rog.ie/blog/css-star-rater). If i maked a mistake somewhere, please correct it in the comments below. I googled more much things, but sadly, doesn't work :/

Comment: https://github.com/raskchanky/star-rating worth looking.

Answer (score 4):

You can tweak your markup/CSS and achieve this by using the below approach (updated with some of your code), which I wrote some time back. Note that this also wraps your inputs within a more semantic `fieldset` structure, as well as better UI in terms of currently hovered / currently selected items. If part of a form, the relevant value will also be correctly submitted.

```js
$('.rating input').change(
  function() {
    $('#choice').text(this.value + ' stars');
  }
)
```

```css
.rating {
  float: left;
  border: none;
}
.rating:not(:checked) > input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.rating:not(:checked) > label {
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  padding: 0 .1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 200%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #ddd;
}
.rating:not(:checked) > label:before {
  content: '★ ';
}
.rating > input:checked ~ label {
  color: #f70;
}
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
  color: gold;
}
.rating > input:checked + label:hover,
.rating > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
  color: #ea0;
}
.rating > label:active {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="rating">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label for="star5">5 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label for="star4">4 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label for="star3">3 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label for="star2">2 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label for="star1">1 star</label>
</fieldset>

<div id="choice"></div>
```

Comment: That is nice, and it works, but i need the results of voting and one vote per IP/PC and to be centered :-)

Comment: Now, You aren't expecting peoples here to just write the website for you, are you ? That is your place to integrate the answer you find "fitting" in your solution and produce the process, not his or anyone here. We might however be happy to help, AFTER you've tried something on your own and narrowed down the problem, if problem there is :).

Comment: @StefanĐorđević - adding your jQuery to give the current selection value is easy enough, see updated answer

Comment: Sorry, i am new to the site and programming, and for me the most easy way is to people give me full script, and i edit if i can. The 80% here of questions i don't understand, so please forgive me :/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this css based rating system i have built. It is very easy to understand and modify

HTML:

```
<formset id = "rating" class = "rating">
<input type = "radio" id = "r0"  name = "rating" checked = true style = "display:none;"> <label for = "r0" style = "display:none;"></label>
<input type = "radio" id = "r1"  name = "rating"> <label for = "r1"></label>
<input type = "radio" id = "r2"  name = "rating"> <label for = "r2"></label>
<input type = "radio" id = "r3"  name = "rating"> <label for = "r3"></label>
<input type = "radio" id = "r4"  name = "rating"> <label for = "r4"></label>
<input type = "radio" id = "r5"  name = "rating"> <label for = "r5"></label>
</formset>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.rating
{
  color: yellow;
}
formset > label, formset > input
{
  float: left;
}


formset > label::after
{
    content: '★ ';
    font-size: 50px;
    color: lightpink;
}

formset:hover > input:not(:checked) ~ label::after,
formset:not(:hover) > label::after,
formset:hover > input:checked ~ label::after
{
  color: orange;
}



formset:hover > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label::after,
formset:hover > label:hover ~ label::after,
formset:not(:hover) > input:checked~label~label::after
{
  color: grey;
}

formset:hover > input:checked ~  label~ label::after,
formset:hover > label:hover ~ label::after
{
    color: lightpink;
}

formset:hover > label:hover~ input:checked~label~label::after
{
  color: grey;
}
```